# Multiple Joins with Multiple Date and ID numbers Omitting ALL Columns When One Column Does Not Exist For a Specific Date/ID

Tags: sql

I am pulling data from multiple tables using sub queries. I want all the ID numbers (in this case they are restaurant numbers) with all the dates in the date range (in this case fiscal weeks). I am pulling one column from each sub query, but if ONE column (sub query) does not contain data for a specific week and ID number the entire row is omitted, even if there are data for all the other columns for that specific date/ID.

The closest I have gotten is by using CASE WHEN NOT EXIST. This returns the date and ID and the placeholder data in the statement but it repeats the rows.

```
select R.restaurantNumber, P.JobCodeKey,
case when not exists (select 1 from FactEmployeePayrollDay P where P.JobCodeKey = 18 and P.RestaurantKey = 190
and BusinessDateKey = 20190205 ) 
then 77 else p.hours end as hourz,
P.BusinessDateKey
from DimRestaurant R
join FactEmployeePayrollDay P on P.restaurantkey = r.RestaurantKey
join DimJobCode J on J.JobCodeKey = p.JobCodeKey
where R. RestaurantNumber = 195
and P.BusinessDateKey = 20190205
group by r.RestaurantNumber, p.Hours, p.BusinessDateKey, P.JobCodeKey
```

This is small version of my code that I have been testing different things with. This is the only code I have tried that returns anything. But I am getting repeated data (the placeholder and the date/ID). If I pull that date and ID (restaurant number) just from the `FACTEMPLOYEEPAYROLLDAY` table there are 27 rows, but my query only returns 26. (I only want one line returned).

Comment: "Repeat the rows" doesn't really help, unless we know what results you actually *want* and what you are actually getting.

Comment: Could you please specify what is the expected output? Also - you have one sub-query, which I would call more nested-query tbh. Not sure how does it correspond to the whole thing, and how this "small version" of your code says anything about the whole thing...